# Custom Parameters are always Null | Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

## What I Want to Do

When the user taps the URL, it launches the app and pops up a page within the app based on the included custom parameters.

## Problem

I succeeded in launching an Android or iOS app by tapping the URL, but the custom parameter is always null.

## What I Did

The URL that users tap is as follows.

```
https://example.page.link/test/?link=https://test.example.com/?id=${id}&apn=com.example.app
```

`id` is custom parameter that I want to get when this URL is called.

I created link on Firebase Console like `example.page.link/test`.

In `initState`, call `initDeepLinks` function.

```
// openPage opens detail page with id
Future<void> initDeepLinks() async {
  final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
      await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
  if (initialLink != null) {
    final Uri deepLink = initialLink.link;
    print("A: " + deepLink.queryParameters["id"]!);
    openPage(deepLink.queryParameters["id"]!);
  }

  FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen((dynamicLinkData) {
    print("B: " + dynamicLinkData.link.queryParameters["id"]!);
    openPage(dynamicLinkData.link.queryParameters["id"]!);
  }).onError((error) {});
}
```

But those two `print()`s print only `A:`  or `B:` .
I checked URL that contains `?id=$id` and it is correct.

## Tried other URL

When I change the URL to

```
https://example.page.link/?link=https://test.example.com/?id=${id}&apn=com.example.app
(removed `/test` path)
```

It works with custom parameters only on Android.
But do same on iOS, the browser shows `https://test.example.com` page and app doesn't appear.

---

What should I do to make custom parameters?

Comment: What is the content of initialLink.link (print)?